# Could not find the Mozilla runtime

Tags: linux, firefox, archlinux

When to try run "Firefox" in Manjaro 3.16.7.9-1- KDE i get this Error :

**Could not find the Mozilla runtime.**

How to fix it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1- Update with `Sudo pacman -Syu Firefox`

Or if the reinstall doesn't works:

2- Update Manjaro with `Sudo pacman -Suy` and get latest library